# How to fix no sound output from speakers or headphones?

Tags: windows-7, audio

If I plug in speakers or headphones to my PC I get no audio out from either. In my sound setting, the default is set to the speakers and the little icon with the green bars moves up and down with the sound as if it is working.

I have done a clean reinstall of Windows 7 and still have the same problem. Device Manager shows all drivers are good. I've reinstalled them just in case and same issue. I've been using the motherboard CD to install the drivers. I tried to uninstall it and allowed Windows 7 to find the driver automatically and it did but I'm still having the same issue.

What are my options? Or what do you recommended I do?

Comment: Is this issue isolated to the speakers? Have you tried using headphones? And have you tried using ALL the jacks?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the actual port on your motherboard is fried. Either that or there may still be a drive issue. Try installing something like Ubuntu (which as extensive support for different audio chipsets) and see if your sound works there. If it does, then we can rule out a hardware issue. If it doesn't work, then it's a hardware issue.

Comment: It might be better to try a Live CD, no installation required, and this should do the same job.

Comment: live CD? what do you mean by that?

Comment: A LiveCD allows you to run Ubuntu without installing it or overwriting your Windows distro. Follow the instructions here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download